# executing shell commands programmatically in Android

Tags: android, shell, process

I have two commands to execute and get back the data 
My .sh file as two commands and it looks like this

su
dhcpcd eth0

when I try to execute the .sh command in my Android terminal by typing as 
sh filename.sh 
It does not give me output 
but when I do execute it by typing individual line it works. SO when I program as

```
nativeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
nativeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dhcpcd eth0");
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
{
    contents.append(line + "\n");
}
```

What is wrong in this?  I get the output contents as null

Comment: check this out http://tech-papers.org/executing-shell-command-android-application/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exec` in Java starts a new process. So the first line makes a new `su` process, which is going to simply sit there and wait for your input. The second line starts a new `dhcpcd` process, which won't be privileged and so won't produce useful output.

What you want is to run `dhcpcd` using `su`, typically like this:

```
exec("su -c dhcpcd eth0")
```

Comment: It works when I type in terminal and I can see the result.  nativeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c dhcpcd eth0");
 InputStream is = nativeProcess.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
   
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
   
   
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
contents.append(line + "\n");
   }  I still get as null

Comment: @nneoneo- Actually the problem is when I execute that command the output I get is in the form of "fork to background, child pid type". DO you know anything about it, I was thinking it runs on background and connects to child process. SO to catch the response of the command "su -c dhcpcd eth0", there should be another way. If you know of it please do share your info